# resize image in Matlab (make square/scale)

Tags: matlab

So I have an image of someones face that I got by using the `imcrop` function in matlab.

Due to my methodology (similar to the [blobs demo](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/?term=authorid:31862)), the faces aren't always the same size.

One of my image's size is: `103, 57, 3` and another is: `174, 64, 3`.

How can I make an image square using the shortest side? or how could I scale the image to a 64x64 square assuming one or more lengths isn't already 64?

I've tried cropping it again, but I implemented it wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show how you implemented it?

Comment: Using the shortest side? This maybe - "ssz = min([size(img1,1) size(img1,2)]); img1 = imresize(img1,[ssz ssz]);" Disclaimer - Not Tested.

Comment: I just called imcrop again but with a temp matrix which didn't work as it requires a measurement in pixels. Also, thanks for the answer, works fine :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make an image square along the shortest side, and you want to center the result (crop equally from both sides), do this:

```
N = 103; M = 57;
A = rand(N, M, 3); % original image
sz = size(A);
shortest = min(sz(1:2));
longest = max(sz(1:2));
lv = (1:shortest) + floor((longest - shortest)/2);
if sz(1) == shortest
  Acrop = A(:, lv, :);
else
  Acrop = A(lv, :, :);
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply call [`imresize()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html).

To make the image square using the shortest side:

```
sz = min([size(img, 1) size(img, 2)]);
img_resized = imresize(img, [sz sz]);
```

To resize it to `64x64`:

```
img_resized = imresize(img, [64 64]);
```